# Div boxes variable width

Tags: css

Hi I have been trying to get 2 div boxes next to each other where left box is set max-width:350 the div next to that take up variable width. I have managed that with the display-flex. Problem I am trying to solve is that I want to have the 2nd div drop below the first when the screen size is reduced. Eg for mobile screen width

```
<div style="display:flex;">
<div style="max-width:350px; float:left; height:auto; background:gray; margin:10px; text-align:center;">
<img src="Ss0Bba.jpg" style="width:350px" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin:20px">All of my page contents are in here </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something that you are looking for?

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="max-width:350px; height:auto; margin:10px;">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/25/16/29/background-image-4363006_960_720.png" style="width:350px" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="flex: 0 50%; margin:20px">All of my page contents are in here 
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  All of my page contents are in here
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I removed some `CSS` and added `align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap;` to wrap the content and also center the content nicely.

Comment: Yes that is what I am after but for some reason it is still placing the content now below the image when there is a lot of content in the 2nd div

Comment: Alright, I added `max-width` on the second `div` how does it look now? I also added `justify-content: center;` on the parent `div` so that everything is centered on the screen.

Comment: this one works well but I also dont want a max width on 2nd div

Comment: Well, you could use something like `flex: 0 50%;`, for example. Have a look at my answer. In general, I am not entirely sure at what point you want the content to break and how much of the screen width you want the content to use.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent element

and add a `min-width` to your second

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="max-width:350px; float:left; height:auto; background:gray; margin:10px; text-align:center;">
  <img src="https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/30093540/Wave-Background1.jpeg" style="width:350px" alt="" /></div>
  <div style="float:left; margin:20px; min-width: 300px">All of my page contents are in here </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display: block; width:100%; height:100%;">

<div style="max-width:350px; float:left; height:auto; background:gray; margin:10px; text-align:center;">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" style="width:350px" alt="" /></div>

<div style="margin:20px;"><p >All of my page contents are in here </p></div>

</div>
```

```html
<div style="display: block; width:100%; height:100%;">

<div style="max-width:350px; float:left; height:auto; background:gray; margin:10px; text-align:center;">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" style="width:350px" alt="" /></div>

<div style="margin:20px;float:left;"><p >All of my page contents are in here </p></div>

</div>
```